# Question about divisors of values of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This particular question was asked in masters exam for which I am preparing and i was unable to solve it.

> Question : Let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x] $ be a non constant polynomial with integer coefficients . Show that as a varies over the integers , the set of divisors of f(a) include infinitely many different primes .

I am sorry but I am clueless on how to solve this particular problem . There is not anything which could be given as attempt.
For background: I have studied ring theory from Algebra by Thomas Hungerford .

Comment: I don’t normally recommend this but try a proof by contradiction; see what you can say about a polynomial if its values are only divisible by finitely many primes.

Comment: Also the title seems unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $f(a)$ can be $0$ modulo $p_1,...,p_n$ as $a=1,2,...$. Let us show that it also can be $0$ modulo some other  prime $p_{n+1}$.

Suppose that  this $p_{n+1}$ does not exist. Since $|f(a)|$ can be arbitrary large, as $m\to\infty$, $f(p_1^m...p_n^m)$ is divisible by an arbitrary large power of $p_i$ for some $i$.
Let $c$ be the last (constant) term of $f(x)$. That is, $f(x)=xg(x)+c$. We can assume that $c\ne 0$ because otherwise we can replace $f$ by the smaller degree polynomial $g$.  But then $f(p_1^m...p_n^m)=p_1^m...p_n^m g(p_1^m...p_n^m)+c$ is congruent to $c\ne 0$ modulo $p_i^k$, for any big enough $k<m$, this is a contradiction.

Comment: last eightth line of 2 nd paragraph of your answer : "because otherwise we can replace f by the smaller degree polynomial g" But there certainly exists a case when constant term =0 . So, if you are ignoring the case there must exist a contradiction in that case. What is that? Or you should prove that case separately. Please clarify.

Comment: If $c=0$ we can replace $f$ by $g$. Every $p$ modulo which $g$ has a root also works for $f$. Since $g$ has smaller degree we can assme that the set of such primes is infinite (induction on the degree).

Comment: Any other questions?

Comment: unfortunately , I amstill not getting it . Can you please elaborate your that argument Or tell what you mean by line "Every p modulo which g has a root also works for f" (I think it has grammatical mistakes" and "Since g has smaller degree we can assme that the set of such primes is infinite (induction on the degree)" . We never used induction on the degree. Kindly elaborate your answer

Comment: can you please reply to my comment above?

Comment: If $g\mod p$ represents $0$ then $f\mod p= gx\mod p$ also represents $0$.Ok?

Comment: one last question ,in the last line of your answer can you please elaborate on what is th econtradiction?

Comment: The assumption was that for all big enough $a$ the value of $f(a)$ is divisible only by primes from the set $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$. We got a contradiction with that assumption.